# Should I make my own password encryption?

Tags: mysql, security

I have some eshop with login system. The main data stored in MySql. I know that all passwords should be encrypted. But should I use the standard methods or I need my own **for more security**?

Comment: One of the golden rules is 'Never roll your own crypto'.  https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/wnx8nq/why-you-dont-roll-your-own-crypto

Comment: I wouldn't be so confident in my crypto skills, if I were you.

Comment: as well as listening to @Brisbe42 you should use a salted hash, not encrypt passwords. That ensures that the passwords can't ever be retrieved, but can be validated.

Comment: Also, in order to really get the best security here, you should make use of the hashing format prior to it reaching MySQL.  MySQL doesn't natively support strong hashing methods, while your eshop system should, ideally, be more equipped to handle bcrypt and similar industry standards.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655250/why-i-should-not-use-my-custom-encryption-algorithm

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing crypto right is *very hard*. There's very few people in the world that can do it.

Given that you are asking this question, I know for certain that you are not one of those people. You are better off using an existing system.

A few key things to look for:

- You need password 'hashing' not encryption.
- The most accepted popular password hashing algorithm is called bcrypt. Find a library for your programming language that supports it, and use that library.

Comment: I'd recommend not only hashing but also salting. (`bcrypt` happens to include salting, which why it's one of the best choices, yet if for some reason another hashing algorithm is chosen, one has to think of salting.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't definitely make a hash which is completely your own. But if you feel the existing solutions bcrypt are not safe enough for your purpose, you can extend them a little by using Salted Hashing: http://dustwell.com/how-to-handle-passwords-bcrypt.html

In python the salted decryption is handled automatically, but you may use some standard techniques for storage as mentioned at the end of that article (which the author says we need not worry about).